# Maximum value and percentile in array

Tags: arrays, ruby, statistics

I have the following array:

```
array = [{"student" => 1, "cost" => 2, "university" => 2, "room" => 2},
         {"student" => 1, "cost" => 5, "university" => 2, "room" => 3},
         {"student" => 1, "cost" => 1, "university" => 3, "room" => 1},
         {"student" => 2, "cost" => 1, "university" => 1, "room" => 3},
         {"student" => 2, "cost" => 2, "university" => 2, "room" => 2},
         {"student" => 2, "cost" => 4, "university" => 1, "room" => 1}]
```

I want an array that only has the maximum value and the percentile `95` of `"cost"`, i.e.,

```
array = [{"student" => 1, "cost_max" => 5, "university" => 2, "room" => 3, "cost_per95" => 4.7},
         {"student" => 2, "cost_max" => 4, "university" => 1, "room" => 1, "cost_per95"=> 3.9}
```

I have applied this:

```
groupedmax  = array.group_by {|h| h["student"]}
keysmax = groupedmax.keys
arrmax = keysmax.map {|k| [k, groupedmax[k].max_by {|h| h["cost"]}]}
table_max = arrmax.map { |ts| ts[1] }
# => [{"student"=>1, "cost"=>5, "university"=>2, "room"=>3},
#   {"student"=>2, "cost"=>4, "university"=>1, "room"=>1}]
```

but I do not know how to add the percentile `95` to that array. A way to calculate percentile is:

```
def percentile(values, percentile)
  values_sorted = values.sort
  k = (percentile*(values_sorted.length-1)+1).floor - 1
  f = (percentile*(values_sorted.length-1)+1).modulo(1)

  return values_sorted[k] + (f * (values_sorted[k+1] - values_sorted[k]))
end
```

Attentive to your comments.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Thank you for help @mudasobwa. The question is how to add the value of Percentile (95) in the array?

Comment: Please update the question itself with this.

Comment: can you elaborate, what value you want in your "cost_per95" key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def doit(arr)
  arr.group_by { |h| h["student"] }.   
      map do |_,a|
        costs = a.map { |h| h['cost'] }
        imax = costs.each_index.max_by { |i| costs[i] }
        a[imax].merge('cost_per95'=>percentile(costs, 0.95).round(1))
      end
end

doit array
  #=> [{"student"=>1, "cost"=>5, "university"=>2, "room"=>3, "cost_per95"=>4.7},
  #    {"student"=>2, "cost"=>4, "university"=>1, "room"=>1, "cost_per95"=>3.9}]

array = [{"student" => 1, "cost" => 2, "university" => 2, "room" => 2},
         {"student" => 1, "cost" => 5, "university" => 2, "room" => 3},
         {"student" => 1, "cost" => 1, "university" => 3, "room" => 1},
         {"student" => 2, "cost" => 1, "university" => 1, "room" => 3},
         {"student" => 2, "cost" => 3, "university" => 2, "room" => 2}, 
         {"student" => 2, "cost" => 4, "university" => 1, "room" => 1}]
  #=> [{"student"=>1, "cost"=>5, "university"=>2, "room"=>3, "cost_per95"=>4.7},
  #    {"student"=>2, "cost"=>4, "university"=>1, "room"=>1, "cost_per95"=>3.9}]
```

Comment: I exchange the hash and the result changed. ´[{"student" => 1, "cost" => 2, "university" => 2, "room" => 2}, {"student" => 1, "cost" => 5, "university" => 2, "room" => 3}, {"student" => 1, "cost" => 1, "university" => 3, "room" => 1}, {"student" => 2, "cost" => 1, "university" => 1, "room" => 3}, {"student" => 2, "cost" => 3, "university" => 2, "room" => 2}, {"student" => 2, "cost" => 4, "university" => 1, "room" => 1}]´. The result is: ´[{"student"=>1, "cost"=>5, "university"=>2, "room"=>2, "cost_per95"=>4.7}, {"student"=>2, "cost"=>4, "university"=>1, "room"=>3, "cost_per95"=>3.9}]´.

Comment: Is that not the result you want for the amended value of `array`? If not, what is your desired return value? Note that, unlike your original `array`, the values of `"room"` vary for a given value of `"student"`. I've assumed you want `"room"` to equal its first value in each array of hashes having a common value for `"student"`.

Comment: The desired result is to keep the Hash of the maximum cost and to add the percentile to it. Sorry for the bad explanation.

Comment: I see. I made the change to my answer. Please clarify the question to indicate that, for each subarray of hashes for which the value of `"student"` is the same, you wish to return the hash `h` for which  `h["cost"]` is maximum, with the key `"cost_per95"` (and associated value) added to that hash.

Comment: I have other question
'arr = [{"student" => 1, "cost" => 1, "time" => 4},
         {"student" => 1, "cost" => 2, "time" => 5},
         {"student" => 1, "cost" => 3, "time" => 6},
         {"student" => 2, "cost" => 11, "time" => 44},
         {"student" => 2, "cost" => 22, "time" => 55},
         {"student" => 2, "cost" => 33, "time" => 66}]'
I want an array that only has the percentile 95 of "cost", "time" i.e.
'arr_per = [{"student" => 1, "cost_percentile" => 2.9, "time_percentile" => 5.9},
                    {"student" => 2, "cost_percentile" => 31.9, "time_percentile" => 64.9}]'

Comment: I believe you made your last comment into a question, which I answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `merge` to add keys in that hash.

Try this,

```
table_max = arrmax.map { |ts| ts[1].merge("cost_per95": ts[1]["cost"] * 0.95) }
```

or you can try this to do all your calculations in just one line

```
array.group_by{ |x| x["student"] }.values.map{ |gp| gp.max_by{ |st| st["cost"] }.merge({ "cost_per95": "Your calculations" })}
```

Comment: How to add the percentile calculation? The method I have is when it is a simple array. Example: `values = [1, 2, 3, 4]`

Comment: Try this for cost calculation,
`arrmax.map { |ts| ts[1].merge("cost_per95": ts[1]["cost"] * 0.95) }`

Comment: How would you use the method that I wrote ´def percentile(values, percentile)´.

Comment: explain which values you want to pass through `values` array

Comment: If in values you want all cost of that particular student, then try this
`arrmax.map { |ts| ts[1].merge("cost_per95": percentile(groupedmax[ts[1]["student"]].pluck("cost"), 0.95)) }`

Comment: I have the next error ´NoMethodError: undefined method `pluck' for #<Array:0x007f1525bd7b30>´